# Two subgroups of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two subgroups of a group $G$. If $|A| = p$, a prime integer, then show that either $A ⋂ B = \{e\}$ or $A$ is a subset of $B$.

Answer (score 10):

HINT: What are the subgroups of $A$? The fact that $|A|$ is prime makes it possible to describe them completely.

Comment: Funny, I was just looking at what happens with prime $|A|$ for class; the result is so cool!